# Django rest framework & model validation

Tags: python, django, validation, django-rest-framework

Getting started using django-rest-framework, and I'm having some trouble regarding validation.

I have a basic model, and i've applied validators to a copple of its fields (A regular `MaxLengthValidator` and a custom `RegexValidator`, ending up with something like this:

```
class ZipCodeValidator(RegexValidator):
    regex = '^([0-9]{5})$'
    message = u'Invalid ZipCode.'


class User(AbstractUser, BaseUser):
    """
    Custom user model
    """

    # ... other fields ...
    zipcode = models.CharField(
        max_length=5, blank=True, validators=[ZipCodeValidator()]
    )
    description = models.TextField(
        null=True, blank=True, max_length=1000, validators=[MaxLengthValidator(1000)]
    )
```

I then created a `ModelSerializer` mapped to this model, with a few additional fields and methods. This is all served by a very simple `RetrieveUpdateAPIView.

I'm noticing that the validators are not called (i can enter anything in the zipcode field, or exceed 1000 characters for the description).

Quick and dirty solution has been to override the two fields at the serializer level and assigne them the validator there:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    zipcode = serializers.WritableField(
        source='zipcode', required=False, validators=[ZipCodeValidator()]
    )
    description = serializers.WritableField(
        source='description', required=False, validators=[MaxLengthValidator(1000)]
    )
```

This works fine, but i don't like it much. I'd rather have this validation occur at the model level to be safer (i wouldn't having mind custom or additional validation on the serializer, but those rules will need to be enforced in all cases). Since serializers work a lot like django forms, i expected them to call the model's `clean` & cie method before saving them, but a quick look at the [source](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L111) seems to indicate it does not.

This is a bit annoying, it forces me to duplicate much of the fields code if I want to ensure the validation always happens, and i'd rather keep this as DRY as possible.

I might be missing something, but is there a nice and clean way to ensure those validators will be run by the serializer before updating the model ?

*EDIT:* Doubled checked the source, turns out that the instance's `full_clean` method is indeed called by the view before saving it to the db, which in turns ends up running the model's validator. Still lost as to why those don't seem to run, tho.

Comment: Where did you see the call to `full_clean`. I have a similar problem the validation code seems to be never called...

Comment: Hi, i don't quite remember, and i'm not sure which version of DRF i was using either (I don't feel like going through the source again when the recent major release might have changed it). I'll check when i'm back at work, and post a link when i find it back.

Comment: So i was (and still am) using DRF 2.4.4.


`UpdateModelMixin`, which is inherited by `ModelViewSet`, calls its model full_clean in its `pre_save` method (see https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/2.4.4/rest_framework/mixins.py#L182).


I've quickly played around, seems that the validators aren't called even when trying call `full_clean` from the shell....  The code has been changed around quite a bit since the original question tho, and i don't really have a lot of time to spend on this right now, so i'm might be missing some relevant info.

Comment: Thanks @astrognocci for your time. I am using DRF 3.1 and there was no call to the model `clean`-method. Then I saw in the announcement of DRF 3.1 that they took out the call to `clean` deliberately: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#differences-between-modelserializer-validation-and-modelform

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
class ZipCodeValidator(RegexValidator):
    regex = r'^[0-9]{5}$'
    message = 'Invalid ZipCode.'


class MyModel(models.Model):
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, validators=[ZipCodeValidator()])


class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel


>>> s1 = MyModelSerializer(data={'zipcode': '34234'})
>>> s1.is_valid()
True
>>> s2 = MyModelSerializer(data={'zipcode': 'f3434'})
>>> s2.is_valid()
False
>>> s2.errors
{'zipcode': [u'Invalid ZipCode.']}
```

Comment: I don't think this works anymore, because of [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#differences-between-modelserializer-validation-and-modelform).

Comment: Sorry. I tested this again with Python 3.4, Django==1.9.7 djangorestframework==3.3.3 and it works as well. Please test it again.

Comment: Ok, looks like you're right. It won't call `clean` on the model, but it will call the field validators.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I think the first solution you proposed @astrognocci, even if it seems quite verbous, is a good solution for Django REST Framekork v3.0 +,

Indeed, `.full_clean()` method is not called anymore in `ModelSerializer` validation process, as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32834026/why-does-django-rest-framework-discourage-model-level-validation)

So writing custom class validators - that can be used in `Model` and `ModelSerializer` - seems a relevant option for DRY concerns, and consistence.