# Why does Django Rest Framework discourage model level validation?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-models, django-rest-framework

Django Rest Framework serializers do not call the `Model.clean` when validating model serializers. The explanation given is that this leads to 'cleaner separation of concerns', [from the Django Rest Framework 3.0 release notes](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.0-announcement/#differences-between-modelserializer-validation-and-modelform):

> ### Differences between ModelSerializer validation and ModelForm.
>
> This change also means that we no longer use the `.full_clean()` method
> on model instances, but instead perform all validation explicitly on
> the serializer. This gives a cleaner separation, and ensures that
> there's no automatic validation behavior on ModelSerializer classes
> that can't also be easily replicated on regular Serializer classes.

But **what** concerns are the authors of Django Rest Framework attempting to separate?

---

My guess is that they're saying that a model instance should not be concerned about it's own validity. If that's the case I don't understand why.

Comment: I'm with you on this one, it's completely unexpected for the clean method not to be called by DRF when it's called by the Django Admin, Django Forms, in a Shell, etc. It's extra unneeded work for our devs.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are two major issues with the model's "full_clean".
The first one is technical. There are a couple of cases where the full_clean isn't called at all. For example, you'll bypass it when you do a `queryset.update()`.

The second one is that if you have a complex business logic - which is usually why you'll have a full_clean - it's likely that you should do the validation in the business logic, not go down to the models to validate.
Each layer should be responsible for its own consistency and the storage layer - ie models - shouldn't care about the business layer.

Another thing that I can think of is that full_clean will be called once you have a model that comes after the serializer has been doing its validation. At this point, things start getting messy because you have a two-step validation with an object created in between.

If you're using `nested serializer`, you might be stuck here because you won't be able to create nested models before the primary model has been saved which will make the full clean call even messier - some objects will be created, others will not. It's hard to figure out when and what object should be validated with their full_clean and you can be sure there'll be a lot of complaints from users when they'll override the update/clean and figure out the full_clean hasn't been called for every model.
This started becoming a total headache and we prefer to keep things simpler and more explicit.

Comment: Could you explain this part more explicitly? "The second one is that if you have a complex business logic [...] it's likely that you should do the validation in the business logic, not go down to the models to validate." Where would that business logic exist and be called from? Do you mean that a Serializer should be calling some business logic during validation? It seems there are [many opinions](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/250035/where-exactly-should-python-business-logic-be-placed-in-django) on this subject and it's non-intuitive for a new Django / DRF user.

Comment: "Where would that business logic exist and be called from?" In MVC it'll be called in controller (view in django). When you have complex logic like a store that handle live stock, it's sometime better to leave the stock computation to the business layer and let that layer do its own validation. Serializer would then just perform basic checks. Some thoughts about that have been written (https://www.dabapps.com/blog/django-models-and-encapsulation/). Note that it's the design choice that DRF did.

Comment: Hi @Linovia - just for the sake of reference, is this highlighted in DRF's documentation anywhere?

Comment: No, it's not. It's an explanation following a chat with Tom and what is used as a guideline when answering questions on the issue tracker.