# django - Best way to deal with validation checks in model creation

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to figure out how to use validations when creating an object in django.

From my POV, there are 2 approaches:

1. Override the default `validate_field` method of the DRF serializers.
2. Add field-level validators to models and catch any IntegrityError or ValidationError exception when serializer calls `.save()` method of the model.

Both ways seem to have their cons.

By using **approach 1** my models are left "unprotected" from any other `.create()` call of the model besides the serializers. **Approach 2** deals with the above issue, but makes the code more complex since exception handling is neccessary in serializer's `.create()` method.

Is there anyone that has faced a similar issue and/or found a "cleaner" way to deal with this?

Comment: Check this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32834026/why-does-django-rest-framework-discourage-model-level-validation)

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understood you need Django model validation. You can try this approach (I think, this is exactly what you want).

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def clean(self):
        raise ValidationError('Problem during validation')

f = Foo(name='test')
f.full_clean() # This is what you need. f.clean() will be enough, but f.full_clean() will make field level validations (run validators) and checking about uniqueness also.
f.save()
```

In general **Django** never makes model level validations(Does not call `full_clean()`), during model creation.

```
f = Foo(**fields_dict)
f.save() # no validation performed.
```

call it yourself if you want,,,

```
f = Foo(**fields_dict)
f.full_clean() # validation performed
f.save()
```

`full_clean()` method is performed automatically, if you use `ModelForm` class. This is additional hook by **Django**.

Comment: Sure, but that implies that inside my serializer create() method, I have to catch every Validation or Integrity Error thrown from the validation. Is this considered a "clean" solution or implementing additional serializer validations makes it simplier? Thank you

Comment: Write Model Level validations is good idea, if you really need to validate model every time (Especially, when you use Model.save() directly and do not have forms and serializers). If you need validations only in serializers/modelserializers just use DRF serializations. ModelSerializer.create() does not call self.instance.full_clean() for you, as it's done for you in ModelForm. I hope, i was helpful. good luck !

Answer (score 0):

I think that moving the validations down to the model is the safest way to ensure the highest level of reliability, because the validations are going to be applied as long as they are done through **Django** (if you use serializers, validations wouldn't work if **Django Rest Framework** is skipped).

Model level validations can be:

**[Field level validations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/validators/)**: You create a method that makes the validation, and set such method as field validator:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

def validate_even(value):
    if value % 2 != 0:
        raise ValidationError(
            _('%(value)s is not an even number'),
            params={'value': value},
        )

from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    even_field = models.IntegerField(validators=[validate_even])
```

**[Model level validations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean)**: You override model's `clean()` method and perform the required validations:

```
import datetime
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    def clean(self):
        # Don't allow draft entries to have a pub_date.
        if self.status == 'draft' and self.pub_date is not None:
            raise ValidationError(_('Draft entries may not have a publication date.'))
        # Set the pub_date for published items if it hasn't been set already.
        if self.status == 'published' and self.pub_date is None:
            self.pub_date = datetime.date.today()
```

Comment: clean method will stop saving if value is not correct for the fields but it gives internal server error. do you think this can be return similar to field level validation message.