# Instance will be created even when required chart field doesn't set explicit

Tags: django

I created a couple a models like Organization. The problem that I noticed with tests I can use `create` method on a model even if `short_description` is empty or not it will save a new instance.

I did set Validator it does not help

```py
class Organization(models.Model):
    # auto creates with signals pre_save
    code = models.CharField(
        primary_key=True,
        max_length=255,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        help_text='Unique code or id that can be used to identify organization'
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        help_text='Short name of the organization'
    )
    short_description = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        help_text='Brief overview of the organization',
        validators=[MinLengthValidator(1)]
    )
```

Test

```py
# this will pass
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_organization_create():
    obj = Organization.objects.create(name='TEST')
    assert obj.code
```

Desired behaviour is whatever I create `Organization` instance if I don't specify `short_description` will throw error.

Comment: You mean ‘short_description’?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem that I noticed with tests I can use create method on a model even if `short_description` is empty or not it will save a new instance.

That is **correct**. Django's ORM calls will ignore the validators for performance reasons.

You can validate your object by using the [**`.full_clean()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean):

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_organization_create():
    obj = Organization(name='TEST')
    obj.full_clean()  # will raise an error
    obj.save()
    assert obj.code
```

A Django [**`ModelForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) will make a full clean, and thus entering data through a form will result in valid object (well valid for the fields you added to the form). This is one of the many reasons why you should use Django's forms to process user input to model objects.

Comment: Are there any other approach without validators and full_clean? I don't understand why should I do some other actions if I expilictly set `blank=False, null=False`. I expect that to be mandatory and reuired. Whatever I create with `Organization(...).save()`, `Organization.objects.create()`? I already set that field can't be nullable and blank

Comment: @ArtemDumanov: some of these properties, like `null=False` are converted to the database level, but all custom validators are in essence just callables and can be anything, so these can not be converted to the database. You can add a `full_clean(..)` call in the `save()` method, but that will not work for `Organization.objects.update(short_description='')` for example. So in general you can not fix this.

Comment: May I ask you how to deal with this problem if I will use DRF? What and where and how I should validate?

Comment: @ArtemDumanov; DRF does not uses `full_clean` but does the validation through validators defined at the serializer level: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32834026/67579