# Is there a silver bullet for validation in django-rest-framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

While developing I often find myself needing some validation. Example:

**models.py**

```
class Survey(models.model):

     type=models.Charfield({...})



class Question(models.model):

     type =models.CharField({...})

     survey = models.Foreinkey(Survey, {...})
```

**Validation:**

Validate that every question saved to the DB has a question.type that is compatible with the module type. So, a survey of type Boolean could not be linked to questions of type Scale-1-to-5.

**My understanding of validation for this use-case is this (my assumptions might be wrong):**

- Validate in the save() method --> Makes the save() method very
  convoluted for bigger apps
- Validate via field-validators on the models -> only gives access to
  the value and not the instance --> FK relations are hard to validate
  with this.
- Validate on Serializer fields --> Same problem as with the model
  fields and also doesn't translate to django-admin (rules will not be
  enforced on the admin).
- Validate in serializer methods like create() or update() --> works but is also not enforced on the admin, custom commands, etc.
- Validate as part of a pre_save() signal --> Makes it very hard to
  send an appropriate response to the user on error (I haven't actually
  tested this yet).

Ideally, I would be able to have all my validation logic in one place but I haven't yet found a way to achieve this. How do you enforce validation in your projects?

Comment: Django uses `ModelForm.clean()` but DRF does not follow this convention as it seems - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32834026/why-does-django-rest-framework-discourage-model-level-validation

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! Yeah, DRF has a `validate()` method for `ModelSerializer` which is a good way to validate user input. But the validation logic will not be applied to the admin and has to be replicated.

Comment: Does `clean()` have any impact on the admin? I thought this was just for a specific form? @Risadinha

Comment: The admin creates forms using the factories - unless you specify your custom form using the form attribute, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form. If you have a custom form with clean, you could of course in the end call the same method to validate the object from the ModelForm.clean() as well as the serializer.validate() method.